# Changing Screen Resolution in Visual Basic App

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce, screen-resolution

I have an application that needs to run at a particular screen resolution (240x320). I'm detecting screen resolution using Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds, but I have no idea how to change current resolution if it is needed. I'm working on Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 using Windows CE.
Cheers!

Comment: is this specifically about setting the device resolution or resizing the form to the native resolution of the device? (it was a bit hard to gather that from your question) as far as i know you have to make the application resize since you can't change the screen resolution.

Comment: Mobile device can work on QVGA Mode(240x320) and VGA Mode(480x640). If I run it on QVGA mode it looks ok, but when I'm using VGA everything is tiny. I want to do sth. that Application will look the same on VGA and QVGA mode.

Comment: what i meant with "you can't change the screen resolution" was that i know of no way to change it problematically, Windows CE API might have  something but i haven't found anything close to it(also more then likely since it diffrent on a per model basis it will be handled by the screen driver)

Comment: oh and _problematically_ should be _programmatically_ fail auto-correct, these might be interesting to take a look at though: [working with vga screens](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/working-with-vga-screens.1723/) and [forceqvga without pixel doubling and qvga](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/forceqvga-without-pixel-doubling-and-qvga-icon.3568/)